# What are some good strategies for dealing with the end of daylight saving time?

Tags: time, light

It's that time of year again! I always struggle with the end of daylight saving time, when we have to shift our clocks back and suddenly it is dark all the time before I even leave work. I find it really challenging. What are some good strategies for dealing with this?

Comment: Can you clarify what is challenging about it? It might be your sleeping patterns, it might be that the darkness makes it difficult to drive, it might be that the reduced sunlight makes you depressed.... When you describe a clear problem on this site, you get a lot better answers. :)

Comment: To answer the question in the title tongue-in-cheek: *lobby your politicians to repeal daylight savings*. For those who prefer mornings, daylight savings can feel more like daylight robbery. And of course, without daylight savings, you don’t get a one-hour jolt come the change of seasons.

Answer (score 4):

Try using light therapy to give you more energy and help your circadian rhythms. There are many options for S.A.D lights. Your doctor may be able to recommend a particular one for your lifestyle. Some insurance plans might also cover the purchase.

Answer (score 2):

The only option to make it not dark when you leave work is to leave early (or work from home). Depending on where you live, that would probably happen a few weeks later anyway, since sunset will be earlier each night regardless of daylight savings time.

If you're having trouble with you biological clock, i.e. waking up too early or feeling sleepy in the evening (this fall; in spring, it will be the other way around), one simple option is to make the change gradually. Instead of moving the clock (and adjusting your sleep/wake/meal times) one hour on a single night (Saturday -> Sunday), move it twice: 30 minutes on the Friday -> Saturday night, and 30 minutes the next day.

Comment: Our neighbour the dairy farmer reprogrammes his cows by 10 minutes every day in advance. Because the milk truck will suddenly turn up an hour sooner or later and cows can't handle moving their milking time that far.